# Temporary failure in name resolution Ubuntu 22.04 -> 22.10

Tags: networking, display-resolution, netplan, resolv.conf

I recently upgraded from 22.04 to 22.10.

Now I get a 'Temporary failure in name resolution' when I try to ping a domain name

a

`$sudo resolvectl status` shows this for eth0:

```
Link 3 (eth0)
Current Scopes: none
     Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
```

I've followed the instructions in similar posts on here

```
$sudo rm -f /etc/resolv.conf
$sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```

Here is my netplan config:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
     eth0:
      dhcp4: yes
      optional: yes
      nameservers:
       addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
```

But the problem still persists

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 20.04 temporary failure in name resolution for wired](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1358221/ubuntu-20-04-temporary-failure-in-name-resolution-for-wired)

Comment: at the time that `resolvectl status` shows no nameservers, what are the contents of `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf`?

Answer (score 1):

OK, NVM fixed. I followed the instructions here:

[Ubuntu 20.04 temporary failure in name resolution for wired](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1358221/ubuntu-20-04-temporary-failure-in-name-resolution-for-wired)

And that did the trick.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

```
$sudo rm -f /etc/resolv.conf
$sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```

Do not do this!  The expected configuration is with /etc/resolv.conf pointed to /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf.

```
 Ubuntu 20.04 temporary failure in name resolution for wired
```

Do not do this either.  Mangling /etc/resolv.conf by hand is unsupported.