# Ubuntu 23.10 "Temporary failure in name resolution"

Tags: networking, 23.10, resolv.conf

Recently my Ubuntu server has started giving me "Temporary failure in name resolution" when using ping or apt update.
The server is plugged in via Ethernet and I haven't had any DNS issues beforehand, I am unsure what has triggered the issue.

```
    $ ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp57s0f1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 80:fa:5b:6c:4b:56 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp0s20f3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 3c:f0:11:fe:9c:8c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.70/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp0s20f3
       valid_lft 81468sec preferred_lft 81468sec
    inet6 2001:8003:d115:be00:e9a4:d508:1d9c:db9f/64 scope global temporary dynamic
       valid_lft 44458sec preferred_lft 44458sec
    inet6 2001:8003:d115:be00:b2c2:134d:8605:dbe6/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute
       valid_lft 44458sec preferred_lft 44458sec
    inet6 fe80::6d19:c8c7:ba10:706b/64 scope link noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:c0:a1:30 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

ping4 -c1 [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) returns:

```
ping4: www.google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

ping:

```
ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

/etc/systemd/resolv.conf:

```
[Resolve]
# Some examples of DNS servers which may be used for DNS= and FallbackDNS=:
# Cloudflare: 1.1.1.1#cloudflare-dns.com 1.0.0.1#cloudflare-dns.com 2606:4700:4700::1111#cloudflare-dns.com 2606:4700:4700::1001#cloudflare-dns.com
# Google:     8.8.8.8#dns.google 8.8.4.4#dns.google 2001:4860:4860::8888#dns.google 2001:4860:4860::8844#dns.google
# Quad9:      9.9.9.9#dns.quad9.net 149.112.112.112#dns.quad9.net 2620:fe::fe#dns.quad9.net 2620:fe::9#dns.quad9.net
DNS=1.1.1.1
FallbackDNS=8.8.8.8
#Domains=
#DNSSEC=no
#DNSOverTLS=no
#MulticastDNS=no
#LLMNR=no
#Cache=no-negative
#CacheFromLocalhost=no
#DNSStubListener=yes
#DNSStubListenerExtra=
#ReadEtcHosts=yes
#ResolveUnicastSingleLabel=no
```

hostname and hosts:

```
    josh@goose:~$ cat /etc/hostname
goose
josh@goose:~$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 goose

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

I have tried all the suggestions from the comments in this thread [Ubuntu 20.04 temporary failure in name resolution for wired](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1358221/ubuntu-20-04-temporary-failure-in-name-resolution-for-wired)

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Im sure Im doing something dumb

Edits:

```
josh@goose:~$ dig google.com
;; communications error to 1.1.1.1#53: connection refused
;; communications error to 1.1.1.1#53: connection refused
;; communications error to 1.1.1.1#53: connection refused

; <<>> DiG 9.18.18-0ubuntu2-Ubuntu <<>> google.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; no servers could be reached

josh@goose:~$ dig @1.1.1.1 google.com
;; communications error to 1.1.1.1#53: connection refused
;; communications error to 1.1.1.1#53: connection refused
;; communications error to 1.1.1.1#53: connection refused

; <<>> DiG 9.18.18-0ubuntu2-Ubuntu <<>> @1.1.1.1 google.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; no servers could be reached

josh@goose:~$ dig @8.8.8.8 google.com
;; communications error to 8.8.8.8#53: connection refused
;; communications error to 8.8.8.8#53: connection refused
;; communications error to 8.8.8.8#53: connection refused

; <<>> DiG 9.18.18-0ubuntu2-Ubuntu <<>> @8.8.8.8 google.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; no servers could be reached

josh@goose:~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 1.1.1.1

josh@goose:~$ ip r
default via 192.168.0.1 dev eno1 proto dhcp src 192.168.0.43 metric 100
1.1.1.1 via 192.168.0.1 dev eno1 proto dhcp src 192.168.0.43 metric 100
8.8.8.8 via 192.168.0.1 dev eno1 proto dhcp src 192.168.0.43 metric 100
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1
172.20.0.0/16 dev br-69d42fdb989f proto kernel scope link src 172.20.0.1 linkdown
172.21.0.0/16 dev br-5e38ac7d290e proto kernel scope link src 172.21.0.1 linkdown
172.23.0.0/16 dev br-6505df725908 proto kernel scope link src 172.23.0.1 linkdown
172.25.0.0/16 dev br-2f731feeedb8 proto kernel scope link src 172.25.0.1 linkdown
172.26.0.0/16 dev br-526004ac228d proto kernel scope link src 172.26.0.1
172.27.0.0/16 dev br-193bc6e3f760 proto kernel scope link src 172.27.0.1 linkdown
172.28.0.0/16 dev br-0f6713744985 proto kernel scope link src 172.28.0.1 linkdown
172.31.0.0/16 dev br-392c0aaed7be proto kernel scope link src 172.31.0.1
192.168.0.0/24 dev eno1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.43 metric 100
192.168.0.1 dev eno1 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.0.43 metric 100
192.168.32.0/20 dev br-5912277b1486 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.32.1 linkdown
192.168.48.0/20 dev br-d811c4e31395 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.48.1
192.168.64.0/20 dev br-124eed87e585 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.64.1
192.168.80.0/20 dev br-aaa96d8c554f proto kernel scope link src 192.168.80.1 linkdown
192.168.144.0/20 dev br-ba40c893c371 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.144.1 linkdown
josh@goose:~$ ping 1.1.1.1
PING 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.0.43 icmp_seq=1 Destination Port Unreachable
ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted
```

Comment: Please [edit] with `dig google.com ; dig @1.1.1.1 google.com ; dig @8.8.8.8 google.com ; cat /etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: Note that it's supposed to be `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` not `/etc/systemd/resolv.conf` . And that's separate form `/etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: Thankyou @DanielT, have edited with those commands

Comment: 1. Your `/etc/resolv.conf` shows you overrode things and are not using `systemd-resolved` 2. This is no only a DNS problem but rather a general connectivity problem. Please [edit] with `ip r ; ping 1.1.1.1`

Comment: `src 192.168.0.43` looks weird when you have an `ip a` of `inet 192.168.0.70`

Comment: 192.168.0.43 is the machines IP but im SSHing into it from .70

Comment: There appears to be an IP conflict between the machine and the one SSHing. You need to make sure the IPs are the same between `ip addr show` and `ip r`

Comment: @DanielT Sorry Im a bit confused.  How would I do that?  and if you have time why do the IP's have to match?

Comment: Idk anything but to suggest going back to the default config. You have a complex setup of bridges and a bunch of routes. I said the IPs should match between `ip a` and `ip r` because they match on my computer and every working system I used. Possibly because the `src 192.168.0.43` is saying to send on behalf of 192.168.0.43, but either it is not allowed to do that or the machine only accepts or is sent by the router replies destined for 192.168.0.70

Comment: @DanielT even if you could point me in the right direction so I can research the issue

Comment: Thank you! I'll see what I can do. I appreciate all your help

Comment: To reset things, you can move `/etc/netplan` somewhere else. Make sure you have physical access before rebooting. Netplan is what controls NetworkManager on 23.10 unless you changed it

Comment: As to why?: Check launchpad bug 1804487 and check dmesg output for a temporary "reduced feature level UDP" when some return info is too big for a buffer.

Comment: @ubfan1 The problem is with `ping 1.1.1.1`, which is a significantly more low level problem than DNS. Furthermore https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1804487 is about systemd-resolved, but `/etc/resolv.conf` shows that systemd-resolved is disabled